# compare two tables and delete rows from one table if there are similar coumn values in two tables hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, delete-row

[Table description are in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhjg7.png)

Table 1 and Table 2 has rows with A and D .I need these two removed from Table 2 .

Please check the link below for descriptive detail . Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do an `INSERT OVERWRITE` using a `LEFT JOIN` select query.

```
INSERT overwrite TABLE table2
SELECT t2.* 
  from table2 t2
       LEFT JOIN table1 t1
        on (t1.x = t2.p) --use appropriate common column name 
WHERE t1.x is NULL; --where there's no common element in t2
```